# how to call array concept $mbAudio

Tags: javascript, php, css, yii

Hey we have implement the game in Yii framework using java script.

In this project game is maths calculation. once answer is correct audio will play like good answer, nice, superb respectively. those are mp3 format. using javascript plugin which is jquery.mb.js. mp3 is playing only one file. but i want to play all those file randomly. i used the array concept with random() which is not accepted. i pasted here the code please suggest me suitable answer accordingly.

```
 $.mbAudio.sounds = {
           effectSprite:    {
            id: "effectSprite",
            mp3: "<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/audio/s1.mp3" };
```

then i used these concept. its not working

```
 var sprite=["s1.mp3","s2.mp3","s3.mp3","s4.mp3"];
    mp3: "<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/audio/random()* sprite.length",
```

Comment: What does this `randdom()` do in the string?

Comment: @VijayJay It didn't used to be, but that still doesn't answer their question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be this way:

```
var file = sprite[random() * sprite.length];

$.mbAudio.sounds = {
    effectSprite: {
        id: "effectSprite",
        mp3: "<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/audio/" + file
    }
};
```

Comment: var sprite={"s1.mp3","s2.mp3","s3.mp3"};
    var file = sprite[random() * sprite.length];    
    $.mbAudio.sounds = {
               effectSprite:  {
                
                id: "effectSprite",

                  mp3: "<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/audio/"+file ,
                
            }, i put like tis

Comment: Try a `console.log(file);`